# String truncated while transferring from Client to Server - Java

Tags: java, string, client, server, lan

I'm trying to send a detail of client system to server system but the server isn't receiving everthing. It stops printing once it has reached the first line.  someone help me get through this problem.

//Server

```
void connect_clients() throws ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException
    {
        try {
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(7700);
            jButton1.setText("Server Running!");
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);
            ObjectInputStream ois; // = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while (true) {

                    socket = listener.accept();
                    socketList.add(socket);


                    ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    String message = (String) ois.readObject();
                     System.out.println("Message Received: " + message); */*/*this is not printing everything

               }

            }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }
```

//Client

```
void connect_server() throws IOException
    {
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here
            String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +
                            "running the date service on port 9090:");
            s = new Socket(serverAddress, 7700);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream ois = null;
            BufferedReader input;
            String answer;
            while(true){

                 input =
                 new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                 DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());


                 answer = input.readLine();
                 System.out.println(answer);
                 if(answer != null)
                 {
                        oos.reset();
                        String line = "";
                        String command = "powershell.exe  Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | \n" +
            "Format-Table –AutoSize";
                                 // Executing the command
                        Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                                // Getting the results
                        powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();

                        System.out.println("Standard Output:");
                        BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
                        while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
                        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) line.length()];
                         oos.writeObject(mybytearray);

                     }

                      stdout.close();
                      System.out.println("Standard Error:");
                      BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
                        while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {

                            oos.writeObject(line);
                           System.out.println("fdg"+line);
                      //printing the output to a file --start
                              try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true)))) {
                              out.println(line);
                       }
                      catch (IOException e)
                      {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                        }

                    }
                      stderr.close();
                      System.out.println("Done");
                }
            }
            }

       catch (ConnectException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
         catch (SocketException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're wrapping `s.getOutputStream()` in both an `ObjectOutputStream` *and* a `DataOutputStream`. That strikes me as a really bad idea. It probably isn't the issue, given that you're never using `dOut`, but it's still a bad idea...

Comment: And you are doing that in a loop, which makes it worse. Open these streams just once on top of the loop.

Comment: So what is the correct way and the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `writeObject` multiple times on the same `ObjectOutputStream` - but in the *reading* code, you're only calling `readObject` *once*.

You'll need to loop in the reading code, e.g.

```
while (true) {
    String message = (String) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println("Message Received: " + message); 
}
```

Now that will throw an exception when it reaches the end of the stream, I suspect - you should probably have some sentinel value (e.g. null) to indicate "end of data". (I don't *think* `ObjectInputStream` just does this for you.)

Additionally, in your client code, you're creating multiple `InputStreamReader` objects wrapping the same socket's `InputStream` - that's a bad idea.

Fundamentally, I think you need to think more carefully about the protocol between the server and the client - think about how the server is meant to know when the client is finished with one set of output, and when it should send the next process name, etc. Then try to redesign your code so that you only ever wrap any particular stream *once* (although that wrapper can then be wrapped itself, of course). Finally, it seems odd to use an `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream` in one direction, but just plain text in the other direction. Protocols should rarely be asymmetric to that extent, IMO.

Comment: It works and there is no exception throw as well. :)

Comment: Oh no, when I see it using 'JTextArea' i get the problem you were trying to say. What is the way to get out of it? @JonSkeet.

Comment: @question: Read the rest of my answer carefully, and think about *exactly* what you want the protocol to look like. Then I would really start these bits of code again from scratch - they're very messy at the moment.

Comment: Yes it is on in a hurry to finish up this work. What i really want to achieve is to request the client for the client system details, i request it by sending a small message, then there is a chunk of code which return the details and that detail is passed on to the sockets to the server side. I have got everything to work correctly expect the 'while' loop,it continues forever even after the data needed to the server is transferred. When i display the result in 'console' it works fine but when I display in 'JTextArea' it displays and rolls away fast and loops forever. @JonSkeet

Comment: @question: Being in a hurry doesn't mean you can skimp on the design. Take a step back, think about the protocol back and forth, and design it appropriately. It'll be *far* quicker to do that in a measured way than to just try tweaks here and there.

Comment: Okay got that,working on it . But help me get out of the loop where I receive the data from client @JonSkeet.

Comment: @question: You need to know when to get out of the loop, which means you need to put that information in the protocol, which means taking a step back and considering the protocol design, as I've said multiple times. (You don't need to add an @ for the comment to reach me, by the way - you're commenting on my answer, so I'll already be notified.)

Comment: But everything works well and good except for the while loop. If you can give me a hint it will develop it.

Comment: @question: I give up, I'm afraid. There are only so many ways I can tell you that you need to think about your protocol carefully, and make sure you're exchanging enough information so that each side knows how many lines to expect, or when those lines have finished, etc. I'm not going to do this design for you - it's up to you to do the work, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm just asking you for a hint not to design it for me.

Comment: @question: I've given you hints: think about what each end of the conversation needs to know in order to proceed, including when the other side has finished. This comment thread has gone far enough now - I've explained your current behaviour, explained how to get out of it, and the redesign you need to do. I don't think there's really anything more required on this post.